# Survival Curve probability interpretation?

Tags: r, python, survival, kaplan-meier

Once I've plotted the survival rate distribution(s) for, let's say, heart failure patients,

Are survival rates applicable to ANY new person coming in and simply being predicted based on the day they were measured (time)?

Comment: How would you have generated the survival curve in first place? Im assuming data of first diagnosis would be the starting point?

Comment: @forecaster. There's a formula performed on the data using only `time` and `death_event` variables. I mean to asking how it's used on NEW patients.

Comment: The point is, the definitions for the data you fitted relate to how you interpret it for a new patient, as long as the new patients and the fitted data both reasonably modelled as random draws from the population of interest (which may often be doubtful). If the original study utilized randomization to treatment as the basis of its inference then differences between new patients and the group from the original study may cause some bias issues. Even if that isn't a problem, if you're trying to predict information about an individual you need to consider the uncertainty in estimated survival.